# TextGeometry.js and FontLoader.js dependencies were not found

Tags: vue.js, three.js

I use Trois.js to create Vue.js+Three.js app. I installed `Trois.js` library:

```
npm install three@0.127 troisjs
```

I imported some basic elements to my Vue module, just like `Renderer`, `Scene` etc.

```
import {Renderer, Scene, Camera, Sphere} from 'troisjs'
```

When I run `npm run serve` then the error comes up:

> These dependencies were not found:
>
> - three/examples/jsm/geometries/TextGeometry.js in ./node_modules/troisjs/build/trois.module.js
> - three/examples/jsm/loaders/FontLoader.js in ./node_modules/troisjs/build/trois.module.js

What's interesting, TextGeometry and FontLoader exist in node_modules under abovementioned directory:

**..build/trois.module.js**

```
import { TextGeometry } from 'three/examples/jsm/geometries/TextGeometry.js';
import { FontLoader } from 'three/examples/jsm/loaders/FontLoader.js';
...
```

I don't know why this error comes up, I reinstalled `trois.js` package but in vain. Still doesn't work. This is my `package.json` file:

````
{
  "name": "troisapp",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "three": "^0.127.0",
    "troisjs": "^0.3.3",
    "vue": "^3.0.0",
    "vue-router": "^4.0.0-0",
    "vuex": "^4.0.0-0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-vuex": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.0.0",
    "@vue/eslint-config-prettier": "^6.0.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "eslint": "^6.7.2",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.3.1",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^7.0.0",
    "prettier": "^2.2.1"
  },
  "description": "## Project setup ``` npm install ```",
  "main": ".eslintrc.js",
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
````

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`TextGeometry` and `FontLoader` were moved to the examples with `r133`. Meaning `trois.js` expects that you work with a more recent `three.js` version and not with `r127`.

Comment: Ok, so basically it means that I need to install most recent `three.js` library on top of that? I thought that by installing `trois.js` I also install most recent version of `three.js`

Comment: I've never worked with `troisjs` but according to their examples you don't have to install `three.js` separately. The latest version of `troisjs` relies on `r134` by the way.